# USB port randomly behave as 2.0/3.0

Tags: windows, usb, port, usb-3

My laptop used to be fine but since from several months, USB 3.0 feature rarely works. When I connect a USB 3.0 device, it show up as USB 2.0 device (USB Device Tree Viewer) most of the time. If I keep on connecting/disconnecting, it finally work as USB 3.0 after random tries.

Note:

- I've checked several USB 3.0 devices. So it is definitely problem with the port
- I've also reinstalled the Windows since then. No change so far.

What is the possible reason for it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try these two things and report back on them: 1) Insert the USB connector quickly. 2) Boot with the device already plugged in.  

Reason: Slowly plugging in an USB3 device (which has both the pins for USB2 and additional pins for USB3)  can make the USB2 pins connect first. If you insert slowly it might already have negotiated completely to USB2 before the rest of the pins make contact.

Comment: @Hennes Just tried both. Unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: Did you try to clean up the ports with isopropyl alcohol and toothbrush? You need to reach deep into the receptacle to get to USB3 pins.

Comment: Sorry, the USB pins are in front row, my bad... Does your laptop have a regular Type-A connectors (rectangular shroud covering all pin internals), or it is some "slim design" that has an angled shroud that follows laptop case curvature?

Comment: This sounds like a signal integrity issue. Usb 3.0 has significantly faster signaling rates than USB 2. If the attempt to enumerate the device at superspeed fails it will drop to the lower 2.0 rates, which are less sensitive to signal quality issues. It could be dirt as suggested or it could be loosening solder joints.  The best way I know if to debug this type of thing is with logmon, but it is fairly technical. It will show you the link negotiations and show why it went with 2.0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151573(v=vs.85).aspx